# "Illegal string offset 'id'" при попытке обратиться к элементу массива

Tags: php

Вот есть такой кусок PHP кода:

```
public function getAllianceRank($id) {
                $this->procARankArray();
                while(1) {
                    if(count($this->rankarray) > 1) {
                        $key = key($this->rankarray);
                        if($this->rankarray[$key]["id"] == $id) { // В ЭТОЙ СТРОКЕ ПРОИСХОДИТ ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ
                            return $key;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            if(!next($this->rankarray)) {
                                return false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
            }
```

А вот и само предупреждение:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in /var/www/GameEngine/Ranking.php on line 189
```

Я так понимаю, что там должен быть массив, а там строка, правильно? Как пофиксить это предупреждение?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(is_array($this->rankarray[$key]) && $this->rankarray[$key]["id"] == $id)
```